# Offline copy of Phobos documentation

Tags: documentation, d, phobos

Is there a way for me to have an offline (preferably searchable) copy of the Phobos documentation as available [here](http://dlang.org/phobos/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D includes a copy of the documentation, in HTML and CHM format. You can find the HTML files under the `html/d` directory in the zip file, and `d.chm` under `windows/bin`.

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint. Where would my copy be?